# Is it possible to select datatype in comobox in c# web application

Tags: c#, silverlight, web-applications, combobox, silverlight-5.0

I an `c#` beginner and working in web development using **Silver Light-5** in Visual Studio-2010. I have my GUI on running my code which has it's GUI created by xaml and the button clicks are handled in c#.

Now what i have to do is :  (I have 2 problems)

(1) The first one is :
I am trying to create a GUI in which i use combo box which will contain options like this (please see this link) http://prntscr.com/36l58s In this link i select the one datatype among the 5 given `datatypes` (which are byte,sbyte,short,int,long). And after that i want to assign this datatype to a `variable` in c# code like this: (suppose i selected "short" in that)

```
comboBox1.Items.Add("short");
var itemType = comboBox1.SelectedItem.GetType(); //This "itemType" contains "short" now
itemType variable = 10; //  **THIS LINE GIVES ERROR**
```

How to assign this "vraibale" the selected dataType in `combo box` ?

(2) The second one is:
When i select "short" (or any data type) then it again repeats the addition of data types in combo box. For example when i selected "short" (or any). I got this http://prntscr.com/36l6om  and if i again select "long" i go this http://prntscr.com/36l75y

My xml code for to achieve is this

```
    <ComboBox Height="19" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,209,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" SelectionChanged="comboBox1_SelectionChanged" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <ComboBoxItem />
        <ComboBoxItem />
    </ComboBox>
```

And c# code is :

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add("byte");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("sbyte");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("short");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("int");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("long");

            var itemType = comboBox1.SelectedItem.GetType();   
        }
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I have a few questions about your post: 1) You have a combo box that contains some options. Why on the SelectionChanged event handler, comboBox1_SelectionChanged, you are trying to add at the Items collection of the combo box control these options? 2) Where you want to use the selected option of the combo box? I mean you want to get the selected option of the combo box. That's clear. But where you want to use it later. Thanks

Comment: @ChristosPaisios Thanks for the reply. The answers are (1) Actually i am new to webapplication(and comobox as well), I was just trying to create a GUI where i can select the datatype of variable at run time using combobox. This selected dataType i then assign to a variable in my code in c#.(Actually i am reading i binary file and i have to select the byte read stored in 16/32/64 bit integer which must be selected by COMBO Box). Could you please help me  in doing that ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,

```
comboBox1.SelectedItem.GetType();
```

is going to give you the `Type` `string`

One way out for you could be a switch case

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
        switch( comboBox1.SelectedItem as string  )
        {
            case "byte"://Create  a variable of byte and use it. 
                break;
            case "sbyte"://Create  a variable of sbyte and use it.
                break;
            case "short"://Create  a variable of short and use it.
                break;
            case "int"://Create  a variable of int and use it.
                break;
            case "long"://Create  a variable of long and use it.
            default:
                break;
        }
}
```

Secondly, Add the `Items` to the `combobox1` inside the `Initialize` or `Constructor` methods instead of the SelectionChanged event, which is causing repeatative addition.

Comment: let me try i will come back soon to mark it as soon it works.

Comment: Thanks for the second part but first part is not working because i have to use the datatype selected using at comboBox to assigne to a variable to make it of that particular datatype (which is known at run time by ComboBx). If i do this in any of your switch statment "comboBox1 variable =10;" I mean variable is assigned a data type which is selected by ComboBox at run time. Is it possible to make do that ? (please see the last line of code in my first part of question you will get idea of what i want to do.(This one : "itemType variable = 10;"))